# Entity Framework Code First 1 to 1..0 relationship

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, entity-framework-6

I seem to have a unique problem with Entity Framework achieving 1 to 0..1 relationship;
I have two entities.

1. FamilyMember
2. ImageStore

FamilyMember stores the person's details and I have ImageStore where profile picture is being stored but it is not required. So FamilyMember may or may not have a profile picture. 
The problem I have is: When I have a profile picture stored in ImageStore, it retrieves the FamilyMember object with ImageStore data but when I don't have profile picture in ImageStore, whole FamilyMember object comes out to be null instead of only ImageStore object in FamilyMember being null. 
I struggled on this issue for a day before returning for a help.

I am using Sqlite with Entity Framework 6.0

Let me start with two models:

**FamilyMember**

```
public class FamilyMember : PropertyChangedNotification
    {
        [Key]
        public long FamilyMemberId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ImageStore")]
        public int? ProfilePictureId { get; set; }       
        public ImageStore ImageStore { get; set; }
    }
```

**ImageStore**

```
public class ImageStore : PropertyChangedNotification
    {
        [Key]
        public int ImageStoreId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ImageFile { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Byte[] ImageBlob { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int FileSize { get; set; }        
    }
```

Here is my **DataContext**

```
public class ADataContext : DbContext
    {
        public ADataContext()
            : base("name=ADataContext")
        {

        }

        public ADataContext(string filename, string password)
            : base(new SQLiteConnection()
            {
                ConnectionString =
                    new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder()
                    {DataSource = filename, ForeignKeys = true, Password = password }
                        .ConnectionString
            }, true)
        {
        }

        public ADataContext(string filename)
            : base(new SQLiteConnection()
            {
                ConnectionString =
                    new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder() { DataSource = filename, ForeignKeys = true }
                        .ConnectionString
            }, true)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<ADataContext>(null);
        }

        public DbSet<FamilyMember> FamilyMembers { get; set; }        
        public DbSet<ImageStore> ImageStore { get; set; }        

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {                
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();    
            modelBuilder.Entity<FamilyMember>().HasOptional(s => s.ImageStore);                
        }
    }
```

And here is the LINQ statement where I am getting the FamilyMember Data using eager loading

```
familyMember =  _dbContext.FamilyMembers.Include("ImageStore").FirstOrDefault(x => x.FamilyMemberId == memberId);
```

Comment: Nav properties are supposed to be `virtual`, might solve some problems

Comment: *whole FamilyMember object comes out to be null instead of only ImageStore object in FamilyMember being null* -- weird, it's not how EF should behave, if the `ProfilePictureId` and `ImageStore` that nulls, it still acceptable.. is `FamilyMemberId` also null? to elaborate @BradleyDoTNET, your `public ImageStore ImageStore` should be `public virtual ImageStore ImageStore` ([virtual keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx) enables proxy class to make an override of the navigation property)

Comment: Right.. that's what I was saying

Comment: First I tried virtual for the Image Store.  That didn't help.  So I tried removing it thinking I am already telling ef to make image store optional on model creating.  But I confirm that it doesn't work with virtual as well

Comment: @Andy since your `ImageStore` is not virtual, it will always be loaded and therefore, you do not need `Include`. But nonetheless, your code is fine. Are you sure the `memberId` you are passing in actually has a related record? Try running the query directly against the database and see if it returns a record.

Comment: Yes,  the member ID I am passing has a record.  I also checked that I am passing the member id correctly

Answer (score 0):

I think, I finally found a solution to a problem. Database table and model was not matching. There was one required field in model which was not created with NOT NULL constraint. 
When I created a row in database, that field was null and when entity framework was getting that row, it was silently dropping it instead of complaining about it.
Finally fixed the problem by bringing the database in sync with the model.